# Update TextField on Button Press in Kotlin with Compose

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have an application I am building for Android that handles specific math based on user input numbers. So far I have the UI built under different composables but I can't figure out the next step to get outputs to appear.
So far, I have this as my code snippet:

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    companion object {
        var tnksze: Double = 0.0
        var tnkmath: Double = 0.0
        var totalFG: Double = 0.0
    }
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            DeliveryCostCalculatorTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(), color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background) {
                    Row{
                        Column(Modifier.padding(horizontal = 2.dp)) {
                            OutlinedTextFieldSample()
                            ExposedDropdownMenuTax()
                            OutlinedTextFieldCredit()
                            ElevatedButtonSample()
                        }
                        Column {
                            OutlinedTextFieldResults()
                            CheckboxSample()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun OutlinedTextFieldSample() {

    var tankSize by remember {
        mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue("", TextRange(0, 7)))
    }
    Column {
        OutlinedTextField(
            modifier = Modifier.width(180.dp),
            value = tankSize,
            onValueChange = { tankSize = it },
            label = { Text("Tank Size:") },
            keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(keyboardType = KeyboardType.Number)
        )
    }
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun OutlinedTextFieldResults() {

    var gallonsLeft by remember {
        mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue(totalFG.toString(), TextRange(0, 7)))
    }
    Column {
        OutlinedTextField(
            modifier = Modifier.width(200.dp),
            value = gallonsLeft,
            onValueChange = { gallonsLeft = it },
            label = { Text("Gallons in Tank:") },
            readOnly = true,
            enabled = true,
            colors = TextFieldDefaults.colors()
        )
    }
}

@Composable
fun ElevatedButtonSample() {
    ElevatedButton(
        onClick = { calculate() },
        modifier = Modifier.padding(horizontal = 45.dp)
        )
    { Text("Reset") }
}

fun calculate() {
    tnkmath = tnksze * 0.8
    totalFG = tnkmath
}
```

Nothing currently happens on my button press. I eventually want everything to update every second based on numbers the user inputs.

Is there a better way to do what I am trying to do?

I tried changing code to my button as follows:

```
@Composable
fun ElevatedButtonSample() {
    ElevatedButton(
        onClick = { **totalFG = tnksze * 0.8** }, <====================
        modifier = Modifier.padding(horizontal = 45.dp)
        )
    { Text("Reset") }
}
```

And tried:

```
OutlinedTextField(
    value = totalFG.toString(),
    onValueChange = { total.FG.toString() = it }
```

Which I think threw a different error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You currently never assign a new value to the `gallonsLeft` variable. You only initialize it to `totalFG.toString()`, but then never update it.

Also, I am not sure if you will get correct behavior when using a companion object to store your data outside of the Composable functions. This is not common in Jetpack Compose. Jetpack Compose uses the [unidirectional data flow](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/architecture#udf) pattern, so data should be passed downwards the Composable hierarchy and events flow upwards using callbacks.

If you don't have a specific reason to use TextFieldValue, you can simply use String as a type. 
You can try to adjust your code as follows:

```
Surface(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(), color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background) {

    var tankSize by remember { mutableStateOf("") }

    var gallonsLeft by remember { mutableStateOf("")}

    Row{
        Column(Modifier.padding(horizontal = 2.dp)) {
            OutlinedTextFieldSample(
                tankSize,
                tankSizeChanged = { newTankSize ->
                    tankSize = newTankSize
                }
            )
            ExposedDropdownMenuTax()
            OutlinedTextFieldCredit()
            ElevatedButtonSample(
                tankSize,
                onCalculationResult = { result ->
                    gallonsLeft = result.toString()
                }
            )
        }
        Column {
            OutlinedTextFieldResults(gallonsLeft)
            CheckboxSample()
        }
    }
}
```

Then update your two other Composables as follows:

```
@Composable
fun OutlinedTextFieldSample(tankSize: String, tankSizeChanged: (newTankSize: String) -> Unit) {

    Column {
        OutlinedTextField(
            modifier = Modifier.width(180.dp),
            value = tankSize,
            onValueChange = { tankSizeChanged(it) },
            label = { Text("Tank Size:") },
            keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(keyboardType = KeyboardType.Number)
        )
    }
}

@Composable
fun ElevatedButtonSample(tankSize: String, onCalculationResult: (result: Double) -> Unit) {
    ElevatedButton(
        onClick = { onCalculationResult(tankSize.toDouble() * 0.8) },
        modifier = Modifier.padding(horizontal = 45.dp)
    ) { Text("Calculate") }
}
```

We pass the `tankSize` and `gallonsLeft` variables down the hierarchy. Whenever the child Composables want to update these values, they send an event to the parent Compoable to update that value.

---

Regarding the issue with the label, your code seems fine. Have a look at the [official example](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material3/package-summary#OutlinedTextField(kotlin.String,kotlin.Function1,androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,kotlin.Boolean,kotlin.Boolean,androidx.compose.ui.text.TextStyle,kotlin.Function0,kotlin.Function0,kotlin.Function0,kotlin.Function0,kotlin.Function0,kotlin.Function0,kotlin.Function0,kotlin.Boolean,androidx.compose.ui.text.input.VisualTransformation,androidx.compose.foundation.text.KeyboardOptions,androidx.compose.foundation.text.KeyboardActions,kotlin.Boolean,kotlin.Int,kotlin.Int,androidx.compose.foundation.interaction.MutableInteractionSource,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Shape,androidx.compose.material3.TextFieldColors)) and make sure that you have the correct imports:

```
import androidx.compose.material3.OutlinedTextField
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.saveable.rememberSaveable

var text by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf("") }

OutlinedTextField(
    value = text,
    onValueChange = { text = it },
    label = { Text("Label") }
)
```

Comment: Thank you for the insight and direction. I seem to be having another issue, however. To do my math, I need to use type Double, but `onValueChange = { tankSizeChanged(it) },` is throwing an error with `it` being an unresolved reference and `label = {Text` is throwing an error of "@Composable invocations can only happen from the context of a @Composable function". I tried to change the values to TextFieldValue but was getting a different error of a Double not returning as a TextFieldValue. Should I change my Text output to a different module like plain text?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I made a mistake in my answer, see my edited answer. The types of course must match. If you use `TextFieldValue`, then all callback functions need to return `TextFieldValue` data. If you used String, then the callbacks would have to return String. For the calculation, you then have to convert it to Double. If you don't have a specific reason to use `TextFieldValue`, I'd recommend using String. See my updated answer.

Comment: And regarding the label, I edited my answer also, check it out and let me know if that works.

Comment: That part makes a lot of sense now,  thank you. One more issue currently, however. In the line 'onCalculationResult = {result -> gallonsLeft = result.toString()' is throwing an error stating "No value passed for parameter tankSize". Tried to do some digging, but can't seem to figure out why the variables in my "ElevatedButtonSample" Composable isn't being passed the variable. Same thing happens with "gallonsLeft" in a different Composable

Comment: I see, we forgot to pass `tankSize` to the `ElevatedButtonSample` Composable. I edited my answer again, please check it :D

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you for your help! I was able to edit the output the same way as well.